# find edges such that if decreased by one unit, the max flow decreases as well

Tags: network-flow, ford-fulkerson

We are given a flow network $G = (V,E,c)$, where $c$ is the capacity function as well as a maximum flow $f_m: E\rightarrow \mathbb R$ from $s$ to $t$. The goal is to find edges such that if decreased by one unit, the value of any max flow decreases as well. The time complexity should be $O(VE)$.

I found this question in my algorithm book.

**My attempt:** I thought all saturated edges could satisfy this condition. Then I found some counterexamples.

Comment: I suggest you work through some small graphs.  Start with your ideas.  Can you identify any patterns in which saturated edges do work, and which don't?

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61683935/5376789):

> Each arc `u-->v` belongs to some `s--t` min cut if and only if
>
> 1. there is no residual path from `u` to `t`,
> 2. there is no residual path from `s` to `v`, and
> 3. there is no residual path from `u` to `v`.
>
> To prove the if direction, consider the cut consisting of vertices
> reachable from `s` or `u` by a residual path, which is an `s--t` cut
> by (1), has zero residual capacity and hence is an `s--t` min cut by
> construction, and contains `u-->v` by (2) and (3).
>
> To prove the only if direction, we can use an `s--t` min cut that
> contains `u-->v` to show that, for every path from `u` to `t`, from
> `s` to `v`, or from `u` to `v`, some arc in the path is non-residual.
>
> This gets you to `O(n m)` time fairly easily. Maybe that's good enough
> -- if it isn't, there is a literature on answering offline reachability queries that might be useful.